# Is it possible to define a cast between text and a domain representing a uuid to avoid manual casts?

Tags: postgresql, cast, domain

I created a `DOMAIN` as following:

```
CREATE DOMAIN country_id AS uuid;
```

I create such domains for readability. It is much easier to read function definitions which accept a `country_id` instead of a `uuid`.

So, continuing, I have a function which accepts a `country_id`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION list_cities(id country_id) returns SET OF city AS
$$ ... $$ language sql stable;
```

When I have a `text` representing a country identifier (for example coming from JSON parsing), I need to manually add a cast as following:

```
SELECT list_cities((some_json->>'id')::country_id);
```

Is it possible to define a cast which eliminates the need to add the manual `::country_id` cast each time? It would be much cleaner if I could do instead:

```
SELECT list_cities(some_json->>'id');
```

Another example could be replacing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM country WHERE id = (some_json->>'id')::country_id
```

by:

```
SELECT * FROM country WHERE id = some_json->>'id'
```

Is it impossible to avoid such manual casts by defining an implicit cast from `text` to `country_id/uuid`?

Comment: You could create a second function which takes a varchar Argument and calls the first one with the cast.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but the function was just an example. Another example could be replacing `SELECT * FROM country WHERE id = (some_json->>'id')::country_id` by `SELECT * FROM country WHERE id = some_json->>'id'`. I'm wondering if 'any' kind of cast could be avoided by defining an implicit cast, but haven't been able to figure it out so far.